# Make www. A different website than non www.?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns

A client of mine wants to start a redesign of their website, initially only changing the homepage to a new template.

Due to Wordpress not being able to run two different themes / frameworks at once for different pages, I'm thinking I could duplicate the website, and have the Wordpress install powering the new homepage run on http://www.website.com

And run the current (soon to be phased out website) on http://website.com

..  & set a 301 redirect on the current website's homepage to the new (www.) version.

So hitting the homepage will connect to the new website and when someone navigates to a subpage everything will function as it used to.

Would this work as simple as that (just setting the 'A'  record for the www. Subdomain to a different server. Or would accomplishing this be more complicated than this?

The only other option I can think of would be moving the old site to a subdomain and 301 redirecting all sub - pages but I can't risk having the client lose any is their search rankings.

Comment: My recommendation would be to do it all at once. Share an IP address link to the new site with the client, and when they're satisfied with it, then migrate the DNS for the whole thing. This is better for users and SEO than fragmenting the domain.

Comment: Many modern browsers will prepend "www" to an http request that doesn't start with "www". You'd be much safer using a completely different name for your new website, and then switching over once your client is ready. This has the added benefit of being able to thoroughly test the new site before exposing it to customers.